# git command to show branch upstream

Tags: git

git's --help and man page very clearly shows good ways to *set* upstream for a branch, but I have not found a great way to *get* the current upstream.

Unfortunately, `git branch -v` shows only the *relationship* to the upstream branch, and doesn't tell you what remote the upstream branch is using.

I have a workaround, `git config --get branch.branch_name.remote` but is there another way?

Comment: The name of the remote is defined as what your `git config` produces.  The name of the branch *on* that remote is in `branch.<name>.merge`.  Finding your own corresponding remote-tracking branch technically requires going through the `<remote>.fetch` entry-or-entries.  I'm not sure which of these you actually care about though.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A couple of options.

If you pass in the -v parameter twice then git will print the upstream in addition to the relationship

```
git branch -vv
```

You can also use something like

```
git name-rev @{u}
```

Where `@{u}` is a special git reference for your upstream.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I now see that it is actually listed on the --help page, but in an unusual format. `-v, --verbose         show hash and subject, give twice for upstream branch`

Comment: When I use the git branch --v it shows me all of my branches. I only want to show the branch that I am on and its upstream. How can I do this? I have a very large number of branches so it is TMI with what is displayed. Thanks.

Comment: @Elijah pass in --list <branch> after the -vv

Comment: @AndrewC by any chance would you know how to in a single command combine git branch --v --list WITH git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD; 

In order to not have to manually specify the current branch that you are on but make it dynamic? I'm trying to make an alias command..

Comment: @Elijah just "git branch -vv --list $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

Comment: @AndrewC Thank you very much. Works just I needed it to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git remote show upstream` to show the upstream url or `git remote show origin` for the origin url.

Comment: git remote show upstream is what actually seems to show the upstream repo.  I'm not sure if functionality has changed or why git branch -vv is upvoted so much but it does not show me the upstream repos.

Comment: @DanCsharpster so the thing is, "upstream" and "origin" are just names - arbitrary strings. Most casual git uses won't even *have* a remote named "upstream". They'll just have one named "origin", which is just a conventional default name for the first remote (like "master" is for branches). Something like `branch -vv` might use the remote that the branch is configured to "track" or whatever (regardless of its name), but `git remote show upstream` will use the remote that you've named "upstream".